# How to remove a suffix from a string with Applicative regex?

Tags: regex, haskell, applicative

I use [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) library.

I want to remove suffix ".end" but only if it's really a suffix (a tail of a string, not somewhere in the middle of the string) and to use [replace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative-0.3.4/docs/src/Text.Regex.Applicative.Interface.html#replace) for it.

```hs
replace (some anySym <* ".end") "start.end"
```

It works: "start.end" -> "start"

But it does not work with "start.end.extra" -> "start.extra" (I expect "start.end.extra" result, because ".end" is not a suffix more - it's in the middle).

I tried:

```hs
replace (some anySym <* ".end" *> empty) "start.end"
replace (empty <* some anySym <* ".end" *> empty) "start.end"
```

and a lot of other combinations, but it does not work as I expect. Is it possible to remove a suffix with this library?

Comment: Have you tried `\.end$`?

Comment: @markalex it does not parse a string for special regex-syntax, so "$" is not a special symbol for it (`$` is literally matching symbol)

Comment: "End of input" is not a concept that library treats as part of its supported language space. It's just a design choice. If it's what you need, this isn't the library for you.

Comment: @Carl It's not available as a combinator, but `match` and the like let you require it at a whole-regex level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` is for finding all the places in a string where the RE matches, and replacing them with something else. You don't want that, so don't use `replace`. You have a regex defining how you want the whole string to be shaped, so `match` on that regex to get the information from the match:

```
stripEndSuffix :: String -> String
stripEndSuffix =
  let findSuffix = match $ some anySym <* string ".end"
  in fromMaybe <*> findSuffix
```